# how to get ssl cert in Mule esb

Tags: java, mule, esb

Is it possible to get fingerprint from incoming ssl certifiacte in mule esb? May be exist a property for that?
I've tried to get "message.getInboundProperty("http.client.cert")" in a transformer, but it returned null

Comment: Please state to us your research.

Comment: The certificate information is not propagated in the Mule Message, however the message is only accepted if you have a valid certificate in the class path configured on the connector. This means you should be able to [retrieve the ssl certificate fingerprint programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119641/java-programmatically-read-informations-from-a-key-certificate).